# Creating a dictionary with Unity Application Block IoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I would like to create a dictionary and populate it in the configuration file for Unity like shown [here](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/63225). However, that example seems to be from an older version of Unity IoC but I would like to know how to do this with Unity 4.

```
<type ... to="MyTypeServer">
   <typeConfig>
      <property Name="Converters"  KeyType"string" ValueType="IConverter">
          <entry>
             <key>csv</key>
             <value><dependency name="csvConverter"/></value>
          </entry>

          <entry>
             <key>xml</key>
             <value><dependency name="xmlConverter"/></value>
          </entry>
      </property>
   </typeConfig>
</type>


<type name="csvConverter" from="IConverter" to="MyCsvConverter"> 
</type>

<type name="xmlConverter" from="IConverter" to="MyXmlConverter"> 
</type>
```

And here is the class:

```
public class MyTypeServer
{
       public IDictionary<string, IConverter> Converters
       {
           set; 
           private get;
       }

       public void DoConversion(string fileName)
       {
            string fileType = Path.GetFileExtension(fileName);
            IConverter converter = Converters[fileType];

            if (converter != null)
                converter.DoConversion(fileName);
            ..
            ...
       }

}
```

I have been trying for hours and researching but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the codeplex link you posted:

> This is a quick pseudo code of the type of stuff we can have with dictionary.

To me, this reads "we could do something like this if we implemented the feature". Aligns with my experience with unity, I've never come across something like this.

What you *can* do however: register all the converters, have them all injected as array and then build the dictionary yourself.

```
// register in code or in xml...
container.RegisterType<IConverter, XmlConverter>( "xml-Converter" );
container.RegisterType<IConverter, JsonConverter>( "json-Converter" );

internal class ConverterConsumer
{
    public ConverterConsumer( IConverter[] converters )
    {
        _converters = converters.ToDictionary( x => x.FileType, x => x );
    }

    #region private
    private Dictionary<string, IConverter> _converters;
    #endregion
}

public interface IConverter
{
    string FileType { get; }
    void DoConversion( string fileName );
}
```

Comment: I need to do it in the configuration file-using code I could think of many ways to do it also. I have seen some other examples so this is doable.

Comment: Do what in code - register the converters or build the dictionary?

Comment: Both of them because the dictionary will be a kV pair of converters. In our solution everything is done in config file and we cannot do a recompile for plugging different implementations. It has to be just plug and play via config.

Comment: Actually I now see what you mean. I am working on a different task these days but I will try your suggestion over the next few days and let you know. I think it will work. Keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer because I do not have sufficient points to comment. This is what I did to solve my problem. Not exactly a Dictionary approach but it might help.

**My requirements - Store app settings in the Unity XML file as opposed to app.config**

I had various objects which were registered in the Unity XML and they had properties like connection strings, Azure queue names , Azure blob container names, etc. I found myself duplicating these values in the XML very often. I could make my objects read values from *appSettings** element of *app.config* or some other configuration section. However, I chose not to use the app.config for the sake of keeping my objects more testable.

**My solution - Use the <instance> element to register reusable string values**

I registered all reusable connection strings in a single location as shown below and without any duplications:

```
<instance name="cnstring1" value="blah connection string 1"></instance>
<instance name="cnstring2" value="blah connection string 2"></instance>
<instance name="azurequeue1" value="name of receiver queue "></instance>
<instance name="azurequeue2" value="name of sender queue "></instance>
<instance name="azurestoragecnstring" value="your azure storage account connection string 0001"></instance>
```

Reference the name-value pairs using the **dependency** element whereever required.

Example XML:

```
  <register name="i2" mapTo="someimplementation" type="someinterface">
      <property name="Database">
        <dependency name="cnstring1" />
      </property>
  </register>
```

Example C# code snippet:

```
public string Database { get; set; }
```

At run time the property *Database* of the object with the registration *i2* will be set to the value of *blah connection string 1*

**Caveats**

Storing connection strings in plain text XML might not be safe especially if the connection string has username and password values.